# Why does bash echo print 0 for a Python function that exits 1

Tags: python, bash

With a Python function in `testreturn.py` defined as:

```
import sys
def main():
    sys.exit(1)
```

When called from a bash function in `scrip.sh` defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
function test()
{  
   python testreturn.py
   echo $?
}
```

Why does the following command:

`test`

Print

`0`

I would like the bash function to print the exit code of the python script.

Comment: Your Python script never calls the function `main()`, so that `sys.exit(1)` never happens, so it just falls off the end of the script and returns 0 by default.

Comment: I would not use the name "test" for a shell function (or alias or script or...). That's the name of an important builtin command, and overriding it might cause other scripts to fail in *really* weird ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because python will not call `main` by default.  You have to call it explicitly.

You want:

```
import sys
def main():
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks for all answers. Chose this because it included code for solution.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're defining, but never calling the `main()` function. The code finishes as normal (by reaching the end of the file) and return code is 0 in this case.